# Hibernate throwing Unable to locate appropriate constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've an Entity `EnterpriseDocument`.

Something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class EnterpriseDocument extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "enterprise_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Enterprise enterprise;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", nullable = false)
  private Document document;

  public EnterpriseDocument() {
    // Empty constructor.
  }  
}
```

I'm using `Lombok` to avoid writing getter and setter.

I've also written a `CriteriaQuery` to fetch `List<EnterpriseDocument>` based on `enterprise_id`.

```
public List<EnterpriseDocument> getEnterpriseDocuments(Long enterpriseId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EnterpriseDocument> query = builder.createQuery(EnterpriseDocument.class);
    Root<EnterpriseDocument> enterpriseDocumentRoot = query.from(EnterpriseDocument.class);
    Predicate predicate = builder.equal(enterpriseDocumentRoot.get("enterprise"), enterpriseId);

    query.where(builder.and(predicate));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query.multiselect(enterpriseDocumentRoot)).getResultList();
  }
```

But when I try to call `getEnterpriseDocuments()`, it throws error:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.entity.EnterpriseDocument]. Expected arguments are: com.entity.EnterpriseDocument [select new com.entity.EnterpriseDocument(generatedAlias0) from com.entity.EnterpriseDocument as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.enterprise=9999L )]
```

It works if I define this constructor:

```
public EnterpriseDocument(EnterpriseDocument enterpriseDocument) {
    // Setting all fields present in enterpriseDocument one by one.
  }
```

But I'm not sure why hibernate is asking for this constructor and defining it doesn't seem right.

What should be the appropriate approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `query.multiselect(enterpriseDocumentRoot)` with `query.select(enterpriseDocumentRoot)`